# React routing without resetting DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a POC app that includes a third-party map. Using react-router, each time the user navigates to the map this one is created from scratch (loader appearing during few seconds, zoom/rotation/modal displayed/etc reseted).

We could think about storing zoom/rotation/etc in component' state and re-apply them (which the API does not permit anyway) but we especially **cannot afford** the map initialization time on each map display, the user experience is just awful.

*Is there a way to tell react to keep a copy of the DOM tree for this component ? To not reset it ?*

I tried returning false from the 'shouldComponentUpdate' function without any success.

I could also develop my own router, where component's domContainerNodes are simply set to display:none, but it totally feels like breaking React spirit.

Please, any clue is welcomed :-)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import './Map.css';

class Map extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log('Map props:');
        console.log(props);

        /**
         * @see ../../README.md#using-global-variables
         */
        this.ThirdPartyMapAPI = window.ThirdPartyMapAPI;

        this.containerId     = 'map-container';
        this.isMapLoaded     = false;
        this.isMapReady   = false;
        this.areEventsBinded = false;
        this.queuedAction   = [];

        this.state = {
            poiId: props.routeParams.poiId,
            poiType: props.routeParams.poiType,
        };
    }

    bindEventHandlers = () => {
        this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.Map.on('ready', () => {
            this.isMapReady = true;
            console.log('Map has successfully been loaded');
            if (this.queuedAction.length > 0) {
                this.queuedAction.pop()();
            }
        });

        this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.Map.POI.on('tap', (data) => {
            console.log('POI selected', data);
        });

        let commonErrorHandler = (error) => {
            console.error('ThirdPartyMapAPI encountered an error: ', error);
        };
        this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.on('error', commonErrorHandler);
        this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.Map.on('error', commonErrorHandler);
        this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.Map.Route.on('error', commonErrorHandler);

        this.areEventsBinded = true;
    };

    loadDataset = () => {
        if (!this.areEventsBinded) {
            this.bindEventHandlers();
        }
        if (!this.isMapLoaded && this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.load('MeL8ooso') === true) {
            this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.Map.create(document.getElementById(this.containerId), { showMapTitle: false });
            this.isMapLoaded = true;
        }
        this.applyOptions();
    };

    /**
     * Apply options from querystring (e.g poiId to show)
     */
    applyOptions = () => {
        if (typeof this.state !== 'undefined') {
            let action;

            // Show a POI
            if (typeof this.state.poiId !== 'undefined') {
                let poiId = this.state.poiId;
                action = () => {
                    this.ThirdPartyMapAPI.Map.POI.show(poiId);

                    /* Used to go back to POI list and test a new map display
                    window.setTimeout(() => {
                        browserHistory.push(`/list`);
                    }, 4000);*/
                };
            }

            // Perform the action, or queue it if mobigeo is not ready yet
            if (typeof action === 'function') {
                if (this.isMapReady) {
                    action();
                } else {
                    this.queuedAction.push(action);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadDataset();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return <div id={this.containerId}></div>
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: can you post your map `component` implementation?

Comment: @Jyothi Babu Araja: done :-)

Comment: `this.isMapLoaded = true;` is it not working for you?

Comment: Yes it is working, then the map is correctly loaded. Why? Do you encounter an error?